# multi-tenant support for laravel entrust

Tags: laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant

I'm building a Laravel site that has multi-tenant capability. Each tenant (which I'll call a "site," as in a physical location, from here on out) can have multiple users, and some users can be associated with multiple sites; hence I have a many-to-many relationship between my `sites` and `users` table, with the required intermediate `site_user` table to handle the relationships. So far so good.

I'm also using `Entrust` to handle three classes of users - `owner`, `admin`, and `user`. In theory, each user should have roles *per site*. That means that User 1 may have the `admin` role on Site A, but only the `user` role on Site B. If I follow the [Entrust docs](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust), I'm told to attach a `role` to a `user`. But that won't work for me, because if I associate User 1 with Site A and Site B and make him an `admin` he would then be an admin for Site A **and** Site B. Conceptually I feel like the `role` should be attached to the intermediate `site_user` table somehow, perhaps as another field on that table, but I'm not sure how I'd retrieve that field. Another possibility that came to mind was putting a many-to-many relationship between that intermediate table and the `roles` table, in effect creating a `role_site_user` table, but again I'm not sure how I'd actually retrieve that information. Has anyone ever tried what I'm suggesting and have a good way to generate per-tenant roles and permissions for a user?